# Стоит ли помещать значения из props и state в промежуточную переменную перед использованием в React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Изучаю сейчас React по официальной доке и обратил внимание вот на такую вещь. В разделе Components and Props, State and Lifecycle они используют пропсы и стейт напрямую:

```
function Avatar(props) {
  return (
    <img className="Avatar"
      src={props.user.avatarUrl}        <-----
      alt={props.user.name}             <-----
    />
  );
}
...
class Clock extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
        <h2>It is {this.props.date.toLocaleTimeString()}.</h2>        <-----
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Но в следующей главе, например, Conditional Rendering, уже переходят на вот такой подход, с предварительным помещением значения в промежуточную переменную:

```
function Greeting(props) {
  const isLoggedIn = props.isLoggedIn;           <-----
  if (isLoggedIn) {
    return <UserGreeting />;
  }
  return <GuestGreeting />;
}
...
render() {
  const isLoggedIn = this.state.isLoggedIn;    <-----
  return (
    <div>
      The user is <b>{isLoggedIn ? 'currently' : 'not'}</b> logged in.
    </div>
  );
}
```

Я например уже знаю, почему при задании нового состояния на основании значений текущего, лучше помещать текущее в переменную. Но здесь случай ведь другой.

Есть какая-нибудь реальная причина использовать промежуточные переменные в данных случаях?

Comment: Может я не прав и умные дяди укажут мне на мою не правоту но, я считаю, что в `Greeting` код очень избыточен и должен быть так написан как вариант: `return props.isLoggedIn ? <UserGreeting /> : <GuestGreeting />`. А вообще пишут так для того, чтобы везде не писать `this.state` (мне лень лично) и я стараюсь получать в `render` те состояния которые нужны так:  `const { isLogin, isCount } = this.state;` (та же вещь и из this.props)/ Плюс вложенность переменной может быть большой `this.props.first.second.thirt.isLogin` что не очень удобно везде писать. Если что оформлю как ответ.

Comment: Как уже было сказано выше, так удобнее в случае с длинными цепочками; Но также важно присвоение через 'const' чтобы гарантированно запретить изменение;

Comment: @DmitriiSedov, да, подойдет как ответ. С деструктуризацией тоже хорошее дополнение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может я не прав и умные дяди укажут мне на мою не правоту но, я считаю, что в `Greeting` код очень избыточен и должен быть так написан как вариант:

```
return props.isLoggedIn ? <UserGreeting /> : <GuestGreeting />
```

А вообще пишут так для того, чтобы везде не писать this.state (мне лень лично) и я стараюсь получать в render те состояния которые нужны так:

```
const { isLogin, isCount } = this.state;
```

(та же вещь и из this.props) Плюс вложенность переменной может быть большой `this.props.first.second.thirt.isLogin` что не очень удобно везде писать